# why value change in jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery

in this blow code, after printing $tarikh_sal i can see `2012-10-27` correctly, but in `$.post` that changed to `1975`, i do not change that. why?

**php code**

```
echo $tarikh_sal; //->2012-10-27
if ( $khoms > 0) 
{?>
    <script>
        $.post("actions.php",{ kh:<?php echo $kh;?> , tarikh_sal:<?php echo $tarikh_sal;?> , postaction:'sabte_kh'},
        function(data){
            alert(data.message);
        },'json');
    </script>
<?}
```

**FIREBUG:**

```
kh=2397897533&tarikh_sal=1975&postaction=sabte_kh
```

Comment: try putting it in quotes `tarikh_sal:'<?php echo $tarikh_sal;?>'`

Comment: Hi, I am confused , You say that when you print `$tarikh_sal`  than it's value was `1975` and you have assigned it to `tarikh_sal` and`$.post` changed it to `1975` so what is issue both value are same..please clear your question

Answer (score 3):

That is because `2012-10-27 = 1975`
This happens because in the script it gets printed as `tarikh_sal:2012-10-27` and javascript does the math there...

Try putting it in quotes to use it as a string. `tarikh_sal:'2012-10-27'`

```
tarikh_sal:'<?php echo $tarikh_sal;?>'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not enclosing the date in string format.

```
echo $tarikh_sal; //->2012-10-27
if ( $khoms > 0) 
{?>
    <script>
        $.post("actions.php",{ kh:'<?php echo $kh;?>' , tarikh_sal:'<?php echo $tarikh_sal;?>' , postaction:'sabte_kh'},
        function(data){
            alert(data.message);
        },'json');
    </script>
<?}
```

Changed :

```
tarikh_sal:<?php echo $tarikh_sal;?>
```

to

```
tarikh_sal:'<?php echo $tarikh_sal;?>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put quotes around the value, otherwise it is evaluated by Javascript:

```
'<?php echo $tarikh_sal;?>'
```